# Command to bring up a list of GNOME shell shortcuts?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

Is there a command to bring up a list of the GNOME shell shortcuts (including user-defined shortcuts)? Ideally, I'd like to use that command to define a custom shortcut for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

open Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know a keyboard shortcut to do this? Or a command that I could map to a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: `gnome-control-center keyboard`